# django- run a script from admin

Tags: python, django

I would like to write a script that is not activated by a certain URL, but by clicking on a link from the admin interface.
How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Clicking a link on browser side doesn't cause server to do anything, unless it is an hyperlink (ie. <a href="">). Please edit your question to clarify: do you just want to restirict this action to a subset of users or you want to stay in the same page after clicking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

But a link has to go to a URL, so I think what you mean is you want to have a view function that is only visible in the admin interface, and that view function runs a script?

If so, override `admin/base_site.html` template with something this simple:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block nav-global %}
  <p><a href="{% url your-named-url %}">Do Something</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

This (should) put the link at the top of the admin interface.

Add your url with named pattern to your urls.py

Then just make a normal django view and at the top of the view check to make sure the user is superuser like this:

```
if not request.user.is_staff:
    return Http404
```

That will prevent unauthorized people from accessing this view.

Next, in your view after the above code, just run the script.

Do that with Python's subprocess module, for example:

```
from subprocess import call
retcode = call(["/full/path/myscript.py", "arg1"])
```